# Amazon AWS Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have problem with AWS API Gateway.

I create my own API and now i want that other users which are in the same group as me and have same roles to access this API via AWS Management console.

The problem is that other users can't see the API which i created (same problem with Lambda functions and DynamoDB which is also visible only for me, not for other users in group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but less secure solution is to assign the AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator policy to the IAM Users, Groups, or Roles you want to be able to use the API Gateway.  This will give them access to all APIs.

If you want to restrict access to a specific API or set of APIs you can create a custom IAM Policy for that API.  You will then assign that Policy to the Roles and Groups you want to have access to the API.  To create the policy, you will need the ID of the API.  It's a long and convoluted process, but it works.  Here are the steps:

1. Determine the ID of the API you want to provide access to by selecting the API Gateway service and clicking on the API.  The URL in the browser will look like the following:

   ```
   https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-east-1#/apis/API_ID/resources/RESOURCE_ID
   ```
2. Copy the `API_ID` to your clipboard for use later.
3. Alternatively you can use the AWS CLI command: `aws apigateway get-rest-apis` and copy the ID from the result.
4. Create a new IAM Policy like this:

   ```json
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "apigateway:GET"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/clientcertificates",
                   "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis",
                   "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis/*"
               ]
           },
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "apigateway:*"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/API_ID/*"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Attach the policy to the Users/Groups/Roles you want to have access.  The first `Effect` allows the user to see all of the APIs but not modify them.  You may want to remove this if you want to be more restrictive.

Amazon has a decent write-up of the IAM Policies for API Gateway here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Comment: yes, this is it...thank you so much. And what was also bad that other user was connected in different region (he was in Oregon and i was in Ireland). I did not think that it can be problem.

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  I forget about the region a lot, too.  I think I'm losing my mind because I know I created something the other day but I don't see it, then remember to change my region!